# reset input form in JSF page

Tags: jsf

I need to build a JSF page with some input form and when click save all this information have to be stored.In particular an input form need to submit a string and then the system makes some check and store or discard the string(for example i need to save an event in my calendar and add some other person).
I tried to use only a view scoped bean but when i call the method to check the string the bean is destroyed, so i change this method to return an empty string and all was fine but when i reload the page the input form are still filled with old information.
How i can reset input or how i can improve my solution.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

After using the value of the fields in your action method, just fill it with a blank value and re render your form. Here's an example:

Facelets code

```
<h:form>
    <h:input value="#{theBean.theString}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{theBean.action}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean code

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TheBean {
    private String theString;
    //getters and setters

    public void action() {
        //do something with the submitted value of theString
        //at the end, clean it manually
        theString = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Resetting a field or property of type `String` to an empty string after its value has been used is a bad advice :)

Comment: i know it isn't good but it works, for the moment. May i shuold split the bean into two: one requestedScope that after saving redirect me to another page, and inject another one viewScope that after saving return void so the bean will be destroyed.

Comment: @Tiny I don't know how can this be a bad advice. Pool, that may work too but the form won't be reset.

Comment: Well, I am just saying what others have already mentioned somewhere (but I  currently do not have some sources to cite). They basically tend to say, initializing a `String` object with an empty string when it is actually intended to be `null` unnecessarily holds an instance of a `String` occupying unnecessary memory. Thus, practicing with empty strings itself is not a good thing. On the contrary, there should be certain special use-cases where initializing a `String` to an empty string might be needed/appropriate - the opposite side cannot be avoided for sure.

Comment: @Tiny oh you meant about using empty String insteaf of null String. I thought the problem would be about the approach to how to clean the fields in the form. I could only say: it's not 2 mbs of ram, so in a real world web app where you will dedicate at least 512 mbs of ram to the server, an empty string that is in the string pool won't hurt that much. If the app is critical in memory e.g. small devices, then this empty string could make a difference. It depends on the environment you will use it.

Comment: Yes your last comment makes a perfect sense for sure :)